# Load Scene after Game Center Match Started (Multiplayer) - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have two layers, single player and multiplayer. Game Center starts up and authenticates the player on the start of the game and Game Center doesn't play any role in single player mode. Multiplayer mode is the only mode that uses Game Center but I want the scene to load after the match (with another real player) has started, so the timer is the same for both people and the match ends at the same time.

Could anyone help me with this? Should I just load the scene beforehand and pause it then resume it when the match starts?

If I should how would I pause it before the scene starts?

Thanks

Comment: i just can't get where the problem is, but my first solution to what you described is to have two scenes with each having only one layer. but I don't know if this may help you or not.

Comment: That's what I have. One layer is the single player mode and another is the multiplayer mode.  Multiplayer mode loads the single player mode but removes any unneeded children (to conserve memory). My problem is that the game starts right when you tap the "Multiplayer" mode. I only want the game to start AFTER the match has started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the new scene when it has found a new player.. And a loading layer to wait for the other player to be connected as well..

You could download the lite version of Infinight which has the multiplayer using game center and try to play it with a friend (both press find game)..